# Let's improve the leaderboard snippet

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, stack-snippets, leaderboard

The leaderboard snippet could use some improvements.

Improvements usually fall into three categories:

- **Formatting & CSS** - make it look better
- **Functionality** - stuff it should do
- **Misc** - everything else

Please answer with suggestions. I've added a few myself.

Comment: The leaderboard post can already have answers posted with improvements or bugs. This seems like a duplicate

Comment: (You can certainly post your suggestions as answers there)

Answer (score 0):

## Keep the leaderboard the same

At the moment there is little problem with the leaderboard, so why fix what ain't broke.

The only real problem is its lack of use, but adding things to the leaderboard code will only make that less attractive.

Answer (score -3):

## *Formatting* - Set a default font

Let's be honest. Most browsers' default font (usually Times New Roman) is pretty ugly. Let's fix that. And propose fonts please!

Answer (score -3):

## *Misc* - Golf up the code

...to allow for longer challenges. We're code golfers, people! We can do this! This is also a good challenge...

Comment: This has already been done by Martin Ender